# How to configure S3 storage on spinnaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker

How to enable s3 storage with an IAM role and how to verify if its working ?
`hal config storage s3 edit --bucket=spintest123 --assume-role=arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/Spintest --deployment` (how to mention current deployment)

it does create and deploy it without errors but i don't see any data or folder in s3 created for it, this is output from hal config storage

```
spinnaker@spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0:/workdir$ hal config storage + Get current deployment Success + Get persistent storage settings Success Problems in halconfig: - WARNING There is a newer version of Halyard available (1.31.1), please update when possible ? Run 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spinnaker-halyard -y' to upgrade

Configured persistent storage: PersistentStorage(persistentStoreType=S3, azs=AzsPersistentStore(storageAccountName=null, storageAccountKey=null, storageContainerName=null), gcs=GcsPersistentStore(jsonPath=null, project=null, bucket=null, rootFolder=front50, bucketLocation=null), redis=RedisPersistentStore(host=null, port=null), s3=S3PersistentStore(bucket=spintest, rootFolder=front50, region=us-east-1, pathStyleAccess=false, endpoint=http://spinnaker-minio:9000, accessKeyId=spinnakeradmin, secretAccessKey=spinnakeradmin), oraclebmcs=OracleBMCSPersistentStore(), oracle=OraclePersistentStore(bucketName=null, namespace=null, compartmentId=null, region=null, userId=null, fingerprint=null, sshPrivateKeyFilePath=null, privateKeyPassphrase=null, tenancyId=null))
```

Comment: Logs from front50 container, show this exception, although I have minio disabled and s3 enabled, why does it show minio in the logs
Factory method 's3StorageService' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: spint.spinnaker-minio

Comment: please post what is your spinnaker deployment type (Kubernetes, local debian ?, minnaker ), post `hal config` output.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues:

- you **halyard** has not been upgraded
- the `hal config storage` output that you posted mentions **minio** as an `endpoint=http://spinnaker-minio:9000`

Basically it should be like this. Dont give a bucket name so Spinnaker creates one. If you want to use your custom bucket refer to the [commands docs](https://spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config-storage-s3)

```
hal config storage s3 edit \
    --assume-role=arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/Spintest \
    --region $REGION
```

Then set the storage to S3 and `deploy apply`

```
hal config storage edit --type s3

hal deploy apply
```

Remember to join us in the [Community Slack](http://join.spinnaker.io/)